# Mandarin version of "because of you" or "thanks to you"

Tags: cantonese

In Cantonese, often times you hear people say 全靠你 (to mean "thanks to you" or "because of you" (e.g., Because of you, I was able to meet my goal.)

[This page](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Expressing_%22thanks_to%22_with_%22duokui%22) suggests 多虧 is the Mandarin equivalent, but someone else said this is not a common phrase.

What's the Mandarin equivalent of 全靠你?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

多虧 means 'largely owe to' ; 全靠 means 'all depend on (thanks to)'

> What's the Mandarin equivalent of 全靠你?

Actually, 全靠你 can be used in both Cantonese and Mandarin

Similar to '全靠' are  '全仗' and '全賴' . All mean 'all depend on'

*'全仗' and '全賴' are more literary; '全靠' is more colloquial*

Comment: thanks once again! you really should change your name to professor ho. :)